# How to remove the outer array but still keep the inner elements in their arrays in a Rails SQL string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this array:

```
array = [["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]
```

How do I remove the outer square brackets, removing one dimension from the array, so it looks like this:

```
array = ["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]
```

I know if I wanted to flatten the entire array, so I get one large array, I could use `flatten`. However,  I just want to get rid of the outer dimension, while keeping the inner elements within their respective arrays.

Essentially I am trying to get the query:

```
 Phone.where(["brand_name in (?) AND os in (?) AND price_category in (?)", ["Nokia"], ["Blackberry", "Android"], ["1", "2"]])
```

But instead, this is what I am getting. Notice one more set of array brackets around the corresponding column values.

```
 Phone.where(["brand_name in (?) AND os in (?) AND price_category in (?)", [["Nokia"], ["Blackberry", "Android"], ["1", "2"]]])
```

This is the method:

```
def self.checkbox_search(params_hash)
    params_array = ["brand_name", "os", "price_category"]
    column_array = []
    key_array = []
    params_hash.each do |k,v|
      if params_array.include?(k)
         column_array << v
         key_array << k + ' in (?)'
      end
    end
  joined_keys = key_array.join(" AND ") + ", " + "#{column_array}"
  Phone.where([#{joined_keys}])
end
```

I am grabbing the `params` hash, and putting it in `checkbox_search`, which goes through the hash and puts the key values in `key_array`,  and puts their values in `column_array`, if they meet specified criteria of key includes `params_array`. Then I join the entire string together in `joined_keys`, then put the results of `joined_keys` inside `Phone.where()` string

Comment: You don't. Do you just want to display the array of arrays without external brackets?

Comment: It's part of a Rails SQL string I'm trying to develop: `Phone.where(["brand_name in (?) AND os in (?)", ["Nokia"], ["Blackberry"]])`. Problem is I"m getting `[["Nokia"], ["Blackberry"]]`, but want to get back `["Nokia"], ["Blackberry"]`

Comment: @EricDuminil I've removed that comment. It's "valid" in that it parses, but it's not the canonical form.

Comment: What do you mean "get back"? You might want to edit your question and put the part about ActiveRecord in there because your application of this seems highly relevant.

Comment: @tadman: What happened to TIMTOADY? If it works and doesn't raise a SyntaxError, that's valid for me. But yes, I guess I see what you mean.

Comment: You're just making it hard on yourself. If you have have separate arrays of  "brand_name", "os", "price_category" etc you can just construct a query with `Phone.where(brand_name: brand_names_array, price_category: price_categories_array)` - there is absolutely no need to use a SQL string.

Comment: @max you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just assembling the arrays the wrong way:

```
Phone.where([ key_array.join(" AND ") ] + column_array)
```

That *appends* the `column_array` values. If you inline them then they'll be pushed down in terms of nesting. Note that `#{...}` has no place here, that's used for string interpolation and it will mess up things badly.

Technically the second version is equivalent to the first due to how it's parsed and assigned:

```
x = [1,2],[3,4]
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
x
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

That notation's normally used for situations like this:

```
x,y = [1,2],[3,4]
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
x
# => [1, 2]
y
# => [3, 4]
```

There's no "outer dimension" you can remove. Either you have an array of arrays, or you have a singular array that's flat.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment about the call to Phone you can try

```
array = [["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]] 

Phone.where(brand_name: array.map(&:last))
```

Comment: `Phone.where(brand_name: array.map(&:last), price_category: array.map(&:first))` to be complete.

Comment: This was a response to the  comment, the question was edited after this response.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is very creative but you're greatly overcomplicating a simple task.

```
def self.checkbox_search(params_hash)
  where(params_hash.slice(:brand_name, :os, :price_category))
end
```

If you only want certain keys from a hash you can use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) or for a params hash you can use [`ActionController::Parameters#permit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit).

There is absolutely no need to construct a SQL string manually. In ActiveRecord you can create `WHERE ... AND ...` conditions by:

```
Person.where(name: 'Max', awesome: true)
# or
Person.where(name: 'Max').where(awesome: true)
```

Passing an array as the value for a key creates a `WHERE ... IN ...`:

```
Person.where(name: ['Max', 'the12'])
```

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Actually knew about the hash and active record querying, but did not know `:a=>[1,2,3]` = `["a in (?)", [1,2,3]]`. Thank you for the education!